# Keeping extra files (todo list, packaging) in a branch

Tags: svn, branch

I was looking for a simple way to keep some todo items and notes in version control along with my personal projects and in the process I came across ditz and bugs everywhere. The Ditz readme mentions that there are 3 different ways of maintaining the file and one is to:

> Keep the issue database in the repository but in a separate branch. Issue changes can be managed by your VCS, but is not tied directly to code commits.

This led me to think that I could use the same thing to keep some files used for packaging in a repository shared with a few other developers that I now keep separate. So I have a few questions:

1. Why should I use/not use this approach?
2. How is this setup? Not specifically for Ditz, but for any files.
3. How does it work day-to-day?

I have almost no experience with branching and everywhere I look it is used to keep an edited copy of trunk that will be merged later.
I use mainly subversion, but an answer for a dvcs is also fine as long as it translates.

**Update**

I looked a bit more into this and this is what I've found. The following apply to subversion.

From the svnbook,

> Subversion has no internal concept of a branch—only copies

which maybe means that svn branches are not exactly what is suggested in the ditz readme. It seems to me that what ditz is suggesting can be achieved using `svn:externals`. Assuming the following structure:

```
/trunk/project1/
/trunk/project2/
/branches/notes/
```

one could set the `svn:externals` property in project1 and project2 to:

```
notes http://reposerver/branches/notes
```

This way updating the working copies of the projects would also get the "external" notes, but committing would need to take place separately for the notes and the other files in the projectX trees. Other than that, everything would be the same as usual. The disadvantages are more or less the disadvantages of svn:externals, i.e. only applicable to directories and that they are defined as absolute URLs.

Nevertheless, if anyone has any further insights I would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many both open-source and proprietary trackers available, I highly doubt it's sensible to use the solution you've proposed. For example, [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) is integrated with your source control (showing commits, allowing to close tickets (or TODO items, if you prefer) in special commit messages etc.). The text-file based TODO list isn't that flexible; you should also consider of you really need to put your tasks in the file other than the normal task tracker. Maybe you're not focusing on the essential problem?

Comment: There are a few reasons that I don't want something like trac or redmine. Mainly it is not practical right now to setup a self-hosted solution and I want to avoid relying on cloud as much as possible. Also for my small projects, some of which are just documents, it may be an overkill or not well matched as I am not just looking to store bugs that way. Your suggestion is definitely valid though.